# Can I package the IPython Notebook, dependencies and additional modules?

Tags: python, virtualenv, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I need the following working environment for a project with several developers:

- python3
- ipython (notebook)
- numpy
- networkx
- matplotlib

Installing these packages on different systems (OSX, Ubuntu, Suse) is time-consuming and problems are quite likely in my experience. Is it possible to package them (maybe with `virtualenv`) into a single repository which users can simply clone and start working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no Windows in your list, which is fortunate.

I would do this by creating a single repo that they can clone. You could put the required Python 3.3 installer in the repo and request people to install that if they have not done so yet.

After cloning the repo, your collaborators would then do the following:

First ensure that virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper are installed globally:

```
sudo pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
```

Activate virtualenvwrapper:

```
# consider adding this to ~/.profile or equivalent
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Create and activate ipy virtual environment:

```
mkvirtualenv ipy
```

Install the necessary requirements:

```
pip install -r repo/reqs.txt
```

repo/reqs.txt contains the following:

```
tornado
pyzmq
ipython
numpy
matplotlib
```

In future, they would just do:

```
workon ipy
```

to activate the relevant virtualenv, and then:

```
ipython notebook
```

to start the ipython notebook.

Comment: nice rundown on how to do this soup to nuts

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an all in one installer like Anaconda or EPD. I don't think a single repo to clone will work as, I guess many thing like numpy will need a compile step.

Comment: since the original post didn't mention windows in the question. For users who are on windows I would recommend [winpython3][1] that is specially designed for scientific python and includes the above mentioned package.


  [1]: http://code.google.com/p/winpython/downloads/detail?name=WinPython-32bit-3.3.0.0beta2.exe